# How to Set a Range of Data in request URL from DOL API Returning Unemployment Insurance Claims?

Tags: api, labor

I tried a request,

http://api.dol.gov//V1/Statistics/OUI_InitialClaims/unemploymentInsuranceInitialClaims?KEY=mykey

, but it returns old data.

How can I set range of data in request url?